# Segmentation Fault calling a member function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class x { };

class y : virtual public x
{
public:
    virtual void f1() { cout << "woekd"; };
protected:
    y();
    ~y();
};

class z : virtual public y
{
public:
    virtual void f1() { cout << "woekd"; }
protected:
    z();
    ~z();
};

class saa : virtual public z
{
public:
    virtual void f1();
protected:
    saa();
    ~saa();
};

int main()
{
    saa *a1 ;
    a1->y::f1();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to create the object, the `a1` pointer points nowhere.

Comment: Argh..! Format your question it hurts my eyes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juFZh92MUOY

Comment: -1 & immediate close vote from me for (a) not asking a question, (b) actually not saying anything at all; and (c) apparently not caring about your code's formatting at all. This strikes me as an insult to all who are expected to answer your "question".

Comment: Seriously this is pretty basic stuff and one that would've been obvious if you'd attached a debugger and looked at the error and stacktrace.

Comment: Well i got it from some one

Comment: plus i am a beginner in C++ :) 
started using it recently 
and stakx I am sorry for the question 
a friend of mine asked me and i posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a1` is an uninitialized pointer. It does not point anywhere. Using it causes undefined behaviour.

You can only dereference pointers that point to valid objects.

In your sample code there is actually no way to create a `saa` since it has protected constructors. You would have to derive a class from `saa`, create an instance of that, and then make `a1` point to that instance.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize `a1` ... so dereferencing it has undefined behavior.

Either use operator `new` or allocate in on the stak.